# Find the smallest unused number from an array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Give an array, how to find next unused number?

`["10", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7"]`, it should return `"4"`

`["1", "2", "3"]`, it should return `"4"`.

Comment: Looks like we are doing your homework? An idea is to 1) sort your array and 2) populate a new array with help of a Range object starting with the first array element and with the same lenght. Then substract array 1 from array 2. The first element in array 2 is your number.

Comment: why wouldn't the first example return "1"?

Comment: @jschulenklopper Sorry for my question, and thanks for your tips. I will try myself.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy Just use the smallest element in array as start point.

Comment: Minor remark - I didn't edit the question because then some answers would contain an inexplicable `to_i` - is that your arrays don't contain numbers but strings (with numeric characters). The second array should be `[1, 2, 3]` with `4` being the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def next_unused(ary)
    sary = ary.collect(&:to_i).sort
    i = 0
    s = sary[0]
    # puts "ary: #{sary.inspect}, s: #{s}"
    while (i<sary.size && (s == sary[i])) do
        # puts "s:#{s}, sary:#{sary[i]}"
        s += 1
        i += 1
    end
    s.to_s
end
```

Comment: uncomment to understand how it works

Comment: I think your first answer is easy to understand, and more simple. I like that one. Thank you.

Comment: i just captured it inside a function: next_unused(["10", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7"]) => 4 and 1.9.3p194 :181 > next_unused(["1","2","3"])  => 4

Comment: Both of them are same logic, let me know what you find dificult I might help you, after all am a ruby pro ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using higher-order functions generally leads to more concise and elegant solutions than explicit loops and accumulator variables...

```
require 'set'
used = ["1","2","3"].map(&:to_i).to_set
1.upto(Float::INFINITY).detect { |n| not used.include?(n) }
```

Using a `Set` makes this solution run quickly even in cases where you have very many "used" numbers. If you know that there will never be many "used" numbers, you can skip converting the array of used numbers into a set. `#include?` works on arrays too.

Comment: +1, definitely the most elegant and concise. Note that you can use `Float::INFINITY` instead of obtaining it by hand. Also `!` should be used instead of `not`, as it's boolean logic, not control flow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about `Float::INFINITY` (answer updated). I personally don't differentiate between boolean logic/control flow when deciding to whether use `not` or `!` -- I use whatever (subjectively) seems more readable. `!` tacked on front of an even moderately complex expression hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps like this?

```
a = ["10", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7"]
actual = a.map(&:to_i)
full = ((actual.min)..(actual.max)).to_a

p (full - actual).first
#=> 4

a = ["1", "2", "3"]
p a.map(&:to_i).max + 1
#=> 4
```